# globalProvider Issue with v2.0 preview

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm having the same issue with the new 2.0 preview as per [this issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/651), and the same fix worked (thanks!). However, is there any guidance on how to access the global provider going forward, with v2, so we can prepare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v2.0 should work the same as v1.x and this is a bug that we need to fix before release, there shouldn't be anything you need to do here.